How to train a yolov7 model on our own dataset?
When I try to train my model by executing the code cell below:
python train.py --img-size 2048 --cfg cfg/training/yolov7.yaml --hyp data/road_sign_data.yaml --batch 8 --epochs 100 --data data/road_sign.yaml --weights yolov7_training.pt --workers 24 --name yolo_road_det
I have the following error message :
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\531558\Documents\streamline2\yolov7\train.py", line 12, in 
import torch.distributed as dist
File "C:\Users\531558\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\torch_init_.py", line 141, in 
raise err
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\531558\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll" or one of its dependencies.
It looks like it can not import torch.distibuted
I tried to change the version of python I am using (from 3.12 to 3.11.9) but it still does not work. I also tried many other way to do the training of a yolov7 model but none of them were working... If you have any solution it would be very helpful

You need to install pytorch on your system and check that it works:
https://pytorch.org/
^^ scroll down and pick the appropriate system you're using, pip or conda, windows or mac or linux, Cuda or not and then copy/paste the command it gives you to install torch/pytorch and related libs.
Can check the install worked by running:
python -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"
Should see output something like:
2.3.0+cu118
or whatever version of pytorch you got... if have an nvidia card definitely get the CUDA support ones.

Also worth noting most AI things work with CUDA 11.8, only some things will work with or use anything from the 12.1 API/version and if your card supports 12.1 it'll support 11.8 from what I've seen (use nvidia-smi to see some details about your driver if have nvidia card)

Thanks for your answer. I alredy did it but I got the following result :
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\531558\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\torch_init_.py", line 141, in 
raise err
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\531558\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll" or one of its dependencies.

Eh so the pytorch didn't go as planned, would suggest just blow away that site-packages and/or just setup a new "virtual env" folder and activate the script  in there before doing any installs or running things (if using vs-code can select the python interpreter with ctrl+shift+p and type "python interpreter" select path and choose the one in  the .venv folder you make)

Make sure to select the correct target OS and all on the pytorch.org page or it can give you versions that won't work on your system and then tend to run into this problem, is basically the biggest slowdown to working with AI models in general.

https://github.com/shusain/python-tutorials/blob/main/1-start-here-virtual-environment.md <-- have some instructions for quickstart with virtual env or can look up the "venv" module docs for more details.

I want to say shm is a shared memory thing and dll is a dynamically linked library so it was basically expecting some library to already be available on your system path but was missing (so either it missed picking it up or was assuming was already present on your system)

ok Thanks, I did it, now I need to reinstall the differnts moduls (numpy, torch...) I do it right now and I keep you in touch

Yup yup, just FYI too I haven't actually use YoloV7 but real similar issues with the setup when doing YoloV8 and 9/10 times it ends up being the pytorch install that trips me up too.

It seems to work, I mean I don't have warning messages anymore, but I just do not find the weight's file, but I will look for that. Anyway, thank you very much you were such a big help !

Cool if this resolved the issue you posted here then go ahead and accept it whenever so others can find it if they hit the same error message and end up here.
